# Struts 2 FilterDispatcher deprecated

Tags: java, struts2

I have searched a lot over the internet to know why Struts 2 `FilterDispatcher` has been deprecated. I did not find any credible, technically sound answers.

In most of the posts it's written that there were *some issues* with `FilterDispatcher`. 
Is there no official explanation for this?

Comment: Even the documentation is unclear: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/webxml.html

Answer (score 6):

The original discussion is [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/struts-dev/200806.mbox/%3C436d9a250806210821u17c2fb7bs3efb5fbaff490b63@mail.gmail.com%3E):

The nutshell version is that:

1. The code is simpler
2. The code is more flexible

One reason it was simplified was to accommodate OSGi.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Kind of explains the thing!